# Ti is not defined in TideSDK

Tags: tidesdk

I'm new developer desktop app.I use TideSDK for develop.Now I can Launch app with TideSDK Developer.I use php for dev.

I'm not sure in general to use javascript in index.html.

I want to set Width,Height my app and I want to set notification in my app when database update.

TideSDK used javascript or not ?

If I want to set Height to fill the screen.How do I do ?

My question may be confusing.Because I not good english.

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checkout the Hello World app and try running it.. it would be good starting point.

https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK-HelloWorld

also checkout the getting started page for more information

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started

Comment: Yes,I checkout the Hello World app from this and try running is good

I don't understand when create new project.What tool you use for create new project ?

I use TideSDK Devloper for create new project